# Difference sets without squares of Integers

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, oeis

I am trying to print numbers occuring in [A030193](http://oeis.org/A030193)
i.e     Let S = set of square numbers;
 a(0)=0;
 a(n) = smallest m such that m - a(i) is not in S for all i < n.

 but I am unable to do it in better than $O(n^2\log{n})$

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= n;i++)
{
    for (j = 0  to T.size())
    {
        if (S.find(i-T[j]))
            goto label;
    }   
    T.insert(i);
    label: ;    
}
```

Here S is Set containing squares and T is set containg numbers of sequence.

Does a better approach exists?

Comment: So it seems you are only printing up to the $n^{th}$ number in the sequence, right?  
What language is this?  It seems you should be able to avoid using "label" and "goto."  What is S, where you have "S.find"

Comment: It's just psuedoCode Orignal code is in C++

Comment: It would make the question a lot easier to read (and so give a better chance of attracting useful answers) if you _explain in the question itself_ what the sequence you're trying to compute is, rather than expecting the reader to go to a different site before they can get told what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: a sieving method will do it in better than $O(n^2)$. Use a boolean array to represent a subset $A$ of $\{0, \ldots, n\}$. Initially set $A = \{0, \ldots, n\}$. Then for $m$ from $0$ to $n$, if $m \in A$, remove all numbers of the form $m + i^2$, $i > 0$ from $A$. Now the members of $A$ listed in increasing order comprise the $a_i$ with $a_i \le n$.